# How do I concatenate a list of files from names listed in another file?

Tags: unix

I have the names of some text files listed in a separate text file named `list.txt`.

I would like to concatenate all of the files listed in this `list.txt` into a single file called `bigFile.txt`.

How to do it using `cat`/`ls` and pipes?

Answer (score 8):

```
{ xargs cat < list.txt ; } > bigFile.txt
```

Comment: If my `list.txt` has a large number of files with long paths, will this approach avoid running into bash command line length issues?